# Parse SQL logs using NXLog, Logstash

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, nxlog

I want to send all logs from Database [Table creation, row insertion, data deletion, data selection etc.. ] to Logstash using NXLog, I have read the following blogs,

1. [Nxlog im_dbi is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519844/nxlog-im-dbi-is-not-working)
2. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/logstash-users/t71AkNH5Ojc

But which seams to be not working for me. Any help will be highly appreciable.

My nxlog config file :

```
<Input sql-logs>        
    Module im_dbi
    SavePos TRUE
    Driver mysql
    Option dbname MySample
</Input>

<Output sql-out>
    Module      om_tcp
    Host        192.168.1.14
    Port        5222
</Output>
```

In logstash config file,

```
tcp {
    port => 5222
    type => "sqllogs"
}
```

Then I have created new table, inserted many records, but no logs visible in kibana.

Comment: I recommend you add some examples of config files you have tried to use to your question, and any errors you get, or what is not working

Comment: @Rumbles I have updated

Comment: Please post your entire logstash config file.  The fragment of the input stanza you posted won't help us debug the output.

Comment: For more debugging advice, check out this page: http://svops.com/blog/?p=26

Comment: I have asked new question regards this in [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27543568/parse-sql-log-from-log-file-using-logstash), Please take a look @Rumbles

Comment: @AlainCollins I have asked new question regards this in [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27543568/parse-sql-log-from-log-file-using-logstash), Please take a look.

Comment: @Rumbles Can you please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27563109/message-missing-in-nxlog-log-shipping) question too?

Comment: @AlainCollins Can you please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27563109/message-missing-in-nxlog-log-shipping) question too?

Answer (score 0):

You should first debug whether the *sql-logs* input actually works.
I don't think it does. Check nxlog.log
There is an SQL directive which specifies the select statement:

```
<Input sql-logs>        
    Module im_dbi
    SavePos TRUE
    Driver mysql
    Option dbname MySample
    SQL SELECT a, b as id FROM tbl
</Input>
```

Note that an **id** column must be present in the result set.